# Converting an array to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically created array like this on the client side.

```
value = [
  [-88.17179185999998, 41.78264698400005],
  [-88.17193080699997, 41.782605419000056]
]
```

and I need to store it in an object format in this order with adding new `"spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326 }`

```
   var params = [
     {
       "x": -88.17179185999998,
       "y": 41.78264698400005,
       "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326 }
     }, 
     {
       "x": -88.17193080699997,
       "y": 41.782605419000056,
       "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326 }
     }
   ];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please try something then post your code as to where you've gone wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `.map()`:

```js
const value = [
  [-88.17179185999998, 41.78264698400005],
  [-88.17193080699997, 41.782605419000056]
];

const objs = value.map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y, spatialReference: {wkid: 4326 } }));

console.log(objs);
```

`.map()` just goes through each element, and runs some function against it, and uses the results of that to make a new array. Very easy for converting elements in an array from a to b.

Comment: Thanks a lots sananime, can you please also let me know where can I find some good beginner resources to learn this .map() ?

Comment: @MonaCoder docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/): [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: As ibrahim mahrir mentioned, MDN is always a great place to learn about vanilla JS functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create array of objects:

```js
var value = [
  [-88.17179185999998, 41.78264698400005],
  [-88.17193080699997, 41.782605419000056]
]

var data = value.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    x: elem[0],
    y: elem[1],
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 4326 
    }
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

Or using es6:

```js
const value = [
  [-88.17179185999998, 41.78264698400005],
  [-88.17193080699997, 41.782605419000056]
]

let data = value.map(elem => ({
    x: elem[0],
    y: elem[1],
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 4326
    }
}))

console.log(data)
```